# sharing contents between two sites

Tags: multi-sites

i setup two sites site 1 and site 2 by using drupal multi site functionality.site1 i consider as the master site and site 2 consider as the slave. some contents in both sites have similar content.when updation made in site 1 its reflect in site 2(only similar contents) for this i try to share the DB. while i try to execute following steps i get following error while i see the site pages

"You are not authorized to access this page. "

i follow this steps:

1.create a db prefix like this $db_prefix = "master_" in site 1 and $db_prefix = "slave_" in site 2.

1. i set the cookie $cookie_domain = 'site2'; in site 1.
2. Then i add prefix like way in site 1
   $db_prefix = array(
   node' => 'master_',
   'node_access' => 'master_',
   'node_counter' => 'master_',
   'node_type' => 'master-',
   );

above thing i did site2 also instead of using 'master_' i use 'slave_'
is there any thing missed out in my con fig.any one guide me do this.
thanks......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multisite isn't really meant for situations where you want to share content.  This is what [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module does.  Essentially, it allows you to have different behaviors for a site with subdomains, but running from the same database.  This is different from multisite, which uses a different database for each site.  I would try starting with that before you go down the road of multisite.

Comment: i also try with domain access module but i am facing some issues like blocks cant display in second domain thats why i move on to this concept.when update is made in the site1 its automatically reflect in site 2 this is my need.is it possible do this will u correct if any thing wrong

Comment: You should be able to do this with Domain Access.  I suspect you just had something configured wrong.  We normally use Panel layouts, and not Blocks/Regions, so I can't help there.