# Scrape articles from one Drupal site to other?

Tags: 7, nodes, importing-exporting

Let's say I have already a Drupal website that has lots of articles and etc. And now I want to build another Drupal website under different domain, and when new article is added to the old site it would be somehow automatically scraped to the new website too?

Both sites are separate and not running under same database nor single installation.

I didn't find a module yet which would do what I need. It has to scrape articles into views lists and also somehow scrape views slideshows content and should be put in sidebars also somehow via views, I didn't find a solution yet, so that's why I asked here.

Comment: [Similar questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/15520/16495) was already asked here. Have you tried anything? Evaluated any solution already described? If so, why do you still have to ask, how did they failed you? If not, why don't you ["search, and research"](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to install a module for this. This sort of thing is provided by the Drupal core. It is called an "Aggregator" and you find it as one of the core modules with the following description:

> Aggregates syndicated content (RSS, RDF, and Atom feeds).

It is not enabled by default.  You need to enable it.

Here is a rundown of the UI:

- administer your list of news feeds. **Admin → Configuration → Web Services → Feed aggregator**
- add a new feed. **Admin → Configuration → Web Services → Feed aggregator → Add feed**
- add a new category. **Admin → Configuration → Web Services → Feed aggregator → Add category**
- configure global settings for the news aggregator. **Admin → Configuration → Web Services → Feed aggregator → Settings**
- control access to the aggregator module. **Admin → People → Permissions**
- set permissions to access new feeds for user roles such as anonymous users. **Admin → People → Permissions**
- view the Aggregator page. **Admin → Configuration → Web Services → Feed aggregator**
- update the feed manually. **Admin → Configuration → Web Services → Feed aggregator**

You need to [set up cron](http://drupal.org/node/23714) to update the feed automatically.

If the site you want to use as the source for your feed is running Drupal 7, the export feed is already in place.  The URL should be `http://example.com/rss.xml`.

Near the bottom of the page of any Drupal 7 (unless you've taken steps to remove it), there should be a symbool like this:

[image]

If you click on it, you should be able to inspect your outgoing feed (provided your browser knows about RSS feeds).

You can of course use this to aggregate content imported from more than one site, but it will also work fine if you just to import content from your own, old site.